# Is there a PHP function to convert a CSV into a PHP object?

Tags: php, csv, oop

I've been looking for a while for a function in PHP that converts a CSV into a PHP object similar to `fetchObject` in PDO.

Is there anything in that direction or do I have to build the magic functions myself?

I've tried magic functions.

Comment: You can parse it as an array, then typecast it to an object. `$csv = (object)array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));`?

Comment: Not going to be like `fetchObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment by [Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel), you can get one object with a property for each row as an array.  This won't be similar to database rows fetched using the APIs and will be awkward to access with integer properties:

```
$result = (object)array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));
```

To get the format of an array of objects like PDO's `fetchObject`, you'll need this, but still each object will have integer properties (probably not what you want):

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return (object)str_getcsv($v); }, file('file.csv'));
```

To do it like you normally would with database functions that fetch a row (but still integer properties):

```
if($fh = fopen('file.csv', 'r')) {
    while($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
        $result[] = (object)$row;
    }
}
```

Better would be to fetch the first line if it has column names/headings and merge that with the data before casting to an object:

```
if($fh = fopen('file.csv', 'r')) {
    $col = fgetcsv($fh);

    while($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
        $result[] = (object)array_combine($col, $row);
    }
}
```

With the `array_map`:

```
$rows = file('file.csv');
$cols = str_getcsv(array_shift($rows));
$result = array_map(function($v) use($cols) {
                        return (object)array_combine($cols, str_getcsv($v));
                    }, $rows);
```

Comment: hey, i have tried this now, but i get this result:
        `array(103) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["scalar"]=> bool(false) } ...`

i only want to read a csv and convert the header to params of my object and each other row to a new instance of my new object.

But i have no idea how i can reach this, with array_map he tells me this: 
    `"arning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements"`

and thats true, the header array is smaller then the content array...

Comment: Then you'll have to add the missing headers to the `$col` array or truncate the values you don't need from the data array.